# Create filter in admin user list

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create filter in wordpress admin `user list` by the column say `account status` i am creating in listing. now i want to filter this user list by using my  column value and this column is in my `custom-user-details` table. I am able to create dropdown for filter but it is not working.Code i tried for this is -

```
//Code to filter user list by Status
function admin_users_filter( $query ){
global $pagenow,$wp_query;

if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='users.php' && isset($_GET['abc']) && $_GET['abc'] != '') {
   $query->search_term = urldecode($_GET['abc']);

   global $wpdb;

    if (!is_null($query->search_term)) {

      $query = $wpdb->get_results( " SELECT DISTINCT account_status FROM custom_user_details ORDER BY account_status ASC " );

    }    
}
}

add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'admin_users_filter' );


add_action( 'restrict_manage_users', 'restrict_abc_manage_list' );
function restrict_abc_manage_list()
{
?>
<select name="abc" style="float: none;">
    <option value=""><?php _e('Filter By Status', 'baapf'); ?></option>
    <option value="1">Active</option>
    <option value="2">Inactive</option>


 </select> 
 <input id="post-query-submit" class="button" type="submit" value="Filter" name="">
<?php  
}
```

and please fine image for more clarification -
[image]